# XSLT: Group XML elements by type and output as HTML tables

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have XML containing elements describing the types and names of objects. Objects are grouped by type into Animated=[Dog, Person] and Inanimate=[Plant, Automobile] categories. A sample XML and desired HTML is shown below.

I would also like to have a catch-all XSL template that would tell me which types, e.g. Cat, could not be mapped to Animate/Inanimate group.

I am using Saxon 9.4.

**XML:**

```
<items>
<item>
    <type>Dog</type>
    <name>Fido</name>
</item>
<item>
    <type>Person</type>
    <name>Bob</name>
</item>
<item>
    <type>Plant</type>
    <name>Tomato</name>
</item>
<item>
    <type>Automobile</type>
    <name>Honda</name>
</item>
<item>
    <type>Automobile</type>
    <name>Ford</name>
</item>
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<th>There are 2 Animated objects</th>
<tr>
    <td>Dog Fido</td>
    <td>Person Bob</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<th>There are 3 Inanimate objects</th>
<tr>
    <td>Plant Tomato</td>
    <td>Automobile Honda</td>
    <td>Automobile Ford</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

*** Adding the following in response to comments ***

The mapping between some object types and Animate/Inanimate groups is known empirically, but the mapping is incomplete. Hence, in this superficial example, if a Cat type is encountered it needs to be printed out in catch-all template.

The biggest problem I ran into was to print out single  and also print out multiple `<tr>`. I tried printing a `<th>` in a template that has `match="items[item/type='Dog'] | items[item/type='Person']"` and then recursively `<xsl:apply-template select="items"/>`, but then I didn't know how to do the catch-all for items that had type I didn't account for, such as Cat.

I also tried to have a template with `match="item[type='Dog' or type='Person']"`, but in order to print out `<th>` I had to do `<xsl:if test="position() = 1">` to print out `<table><th>..</th>`. But this doesn't work because there is no closing `</table>` in XSLT until I process the last item in the group.

I hope this clarifies my dilemma.

Thanks,

Alec

Comment: Specifically, what have you tried and how is it failing?

Comment: Good point, your show no effort. Not to mention that you show nothing at all that is suppose to interpret animate v. inanimate ... or do you expect that to be built into the XSLT engine? As if it could interpret that.

Comment: Animate vs. Inanimate.  This is the question.  Do you intend to provide an xml map which maps "dog" to "animate" and "automobile" to "inanimate" or do you intend to right some long IF/THEN CHOOSE/OTHERWISE sort of functional logic?  What have you done so far?  Is this straight from a text book?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming XSLT 2.0 you could define a parameter with the mapping you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="map">
      <map>
        <key name="Dog">Animated</key>
        <key name="Person">Animated</key>
        <key name="Plant">Inanimate</key>
        <key name="Automobile">Inanimate</key>
      </map>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5.0"/>

    <xsl:key name="k1" match="map/key" use="@name"/>

    <xsl:template match="items">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="(key('k1', type, $map), 'unmapped')[1]">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>There are <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group()), 
               current-grouping-key()"/>
              objects.</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </xsl:for-each-group>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
      <tr>
        <xsl:value-of select="*"/>
      </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way the input sample

```
<items>
<item>
    <type>Dog</type>
    <name>Fido</name>
</item>
<item>
    <type>Person</type>
    <name>Bob</name>
</item>
<item>
    <type>Plant</type>
    <name>Tomato</name>
</item>
<item>
    <type>Automobile</type>
    <name>Honda</name>
</item>
<item>
    <type>Automobile</type>
    <name>Ford</name>
</item>
<item>
    <type>Cat</type>
    <name>Garfield</name>
</item>
</items>
```

is transformed to

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>There are 2 Animated
            objects.
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>Dog Fido</tr>
      <tr>Person Bob</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>There are 3 Inanimate
            objects.
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>Plant Tomato</tr>
      <tr>Automobile Honda</tr>
      <tr>Automobile Ford</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>There are 1 unmapped
            objects.
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>Cat Garfield</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Simply brilliant. Martin, I wish I could contact you directly, but your website's contact form is not cooperating with me.